# Diferença entre avg normal e usando case when no MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, case

Tenho duas queries que supostamente deveriam dar o mesmo resultado, no entanto não está acontecendo.

Alguém pode me explicar porque não é exibido mesmo resultado?

**Query** que me devolve o resultado esperado:

```
SELECT id,
       ROUND(AVG(SinalGPS), 4)
FROM `012017`.gateway
WHERE ID = 8258867
  AND DHEquipamento > '2017-01-22 00:00:00'
  AND DHEquipamento < '2017-01-22 23:59:59'
  AND ignicao = 1
ORDER BY DHEquipamento DESC;
```

**Query** que me devolve o valor não esperado:

```
SELECT id,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE
                     WHEN DAY(gw.DHEquipamento) = 22
                          AND gw.Ignicao = 1 THEN sinalGPS
                     ELSE 0<br>
                 END), 4) AS '22'
FROM `012017`.gateway gw
WHERE ID = 8258867;
```

**Obs:** Preciso fazer da segunda forma, pois preciso que me retorne EM COLUNAS os valores das médias por dia.

Comment: A diferença nas Querys não está na clausula `Where`? Digo de estar trazendo diferença de linhas!

Comment: @Marconi, a diferença nos códigos é que as condições da cláusula Where no primeiro caso, são feitas dentro do CASE no segundo caso. Pelo menos deveriam ser.

Answer (score 1):

Note que no primeiro trecho você colocou como condição a data inteira.
Já no segundo trecho de código, no case, você filtrou apenas o dia do mês.
Tente com o script abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE
                WHEN
                    DAY(gw.DHEquipamento) = 22
                        AND MONTH(gw.DHEquipamento) = 1
                        AND gw.Ignicao = 1
                THEN
                    sinalGPS
                ELSE 0

            END),
            4) AS '22'
FROM
    012017.gateway gw
WHERE
    ID = 8258867;
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta. Mas creio que não seja esse o caso, visto que a tabela tem apenas dados do mês, como o nome sugere. Falha minha não ter dito isso... sorry